# Testing for string equality isn't matching correctly

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of strings. The array was created by parsing a long comma delimited string into several component strings. I can NSLog those components and they appear correctly. However if I test one of those components for the very object the NSLog shows it as containing, the test still fails:

```
NSArray*parseLine=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[newline componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];

NSLog(@"*%@*"[parseLine objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Output:

```
*N/A*
```

So clearly "N/A" is there, those three characters exactly.

However, this fails the test:

```
if ([parseLine objectAtIndex:1]==@"N/A") //never passes
```

Also tried this:

```
if ((NSString*)[parseLine objectAtIndex:1]==@"N/A")
```

Why doesn't it pass the test?

Comment: when you write a string literal "foo" it is stored in memory at a certain memory address. if you use a string literal in an if statement if (something == "foo") you are comparing if something is pointing to "foo" not whether the contents of something is equal to the string "foo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` refers to address pointer as well as string.

To check for equality try `isEqualToString` function

So that will be

`if([parseLine objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"N/A"])`

Comment: i did initially, but SO made me wait 10 minutes before i could actually accept it:)